# PSFTP batch output redirect to local log file

Tags: vbscript, sftp, batch-processing, psftp

I have checked a bunch of different places for a solution to this and it seems so basic, yet when I try it, the thing doesn't like me.

I a writing vbscript which executes psftp.exe, logs into a remote SFTP site, and grabs files referenced in a properties file.

The goal is to redirect output to a local log file. this is the vbs:

```
Public Sub execute(sftp)

    if sftp.privateKey <> "" Then

        cmd =   ".\psftp.exe "  _
            & " -l " & sftp.user _
            & " -P " & sftp.port _
            & " -i " & sftp.privateKey _
            & " " & sftp.name _
            & " -bc " & propFileName _
            & " -v -bc >> D:\SFTP_Jobs\logFile.txt"

        msgBox "Executing: " & ".\psftp.exe "  _
            & " -l " & sftp.user _
            & " -P " & sftp.port _
            & " -i " & sftp.privateKey _
            & " " & sftp.name _
            & " -bc " & propFileName _
            & " -v -bc >> D:\SFTP_Jobs\logFile.txt"


    Else

        cmd =   ".\psftp.exe "  _
            & sftp.name _
            & " -pw " & pw _
            & " -b " & PropFileName _
            & " -v -bc >> D:\SFTP_Jobs\logFile.txt"

        msgBox "Executing: " & ".\psftp.exe "  _
            & sftp.name _
            & " -pw XXXXXXXX" _
            & " -b " & PropFileName _
            & " -v -bc >> D:\SFTP_Jobs\logFile.txt"
    End If



    Dim TheShell: Set TheShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    TheShell.Run(cmd),0 , True
    set TheShell = Nothing


End Sub     'execute
```

This cmd ends up looking like

```
psftp.exe theBankIworkFor@ftp.oneOfOurVendors.com -pw thePw -b batchfile.properties -v -bc > D:\SFTP_Jobs\logFile.txt"
```

This command has been working just fine until I added everything after the -v option...

I apologize in advance if there is something extremely obvious about this

Comment: I read that article and i don't see how my solution is different except the the redirect append.. I've updated the above to include the rest of the sub routine

Comment: The difference is the `cmd /c`.